# Rendering a Simple button view in Backbone & Handlebars

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Totally new to Backbone, and for now my spine is getting stiff getting around a few things.

F.Y.I: I am using Handlebars as my templating engine.

What I am trying to do, is to render a simple Button on my page. For this, in my templates, I have:

```
<script id="newButton"  type="text/x-handlebars">

</script>
```

And it's view is defined like this:

```
var SimpleButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'button', // how can I define other attribute properties such as Text for button?
        template: $('#newButton').html(),
        initialize: function(){ this.render(); },
        render: function(){
              var tmpl = Handlebars.compile(this.template); // what does compile do
              this.$el.html(tmpl());// why is this a function?          
              return this;   
        }
});
```

And finally, I do

```
var btnView = new SimpleButtonView();
```

Which doesn't render anything. What am I doing wrong here :) ? Also, questions to my inline comments are also much appreciated coz I am fairly lost.

Comment: Is the code executed after page load ? Are you using jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something roughly like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script id="button-tpl"  type="text/x-handlebars">
    <button>{{ buttonText }}</button>
</script>
```

JS:

```
var SimpleButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#app'),

    tagName: 'button',

    $template: $('#button-tpl'),

    initialize: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        this.buttonText = options.buttonText || 'Default button text';
        this.template = Handlebars.compile(this.$template.html());
        this.render();
    },

    serialize: function() {
        return {
            buttonText: this.buttonText
        };
    },

    getContext: function() {
        var context;

        if (_.isFunction(this.serialize)) {
            context = this.serialize.call(this);
        } else if (_.isObject(this.serialize)) {
            context = this.serialize;
        } else {
            context = {};
        }

        return _.extend({
            model: this.model,
            collection: this.collection
        }, context);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.getContext()));
        return this;
    }
});

var simpleButtonView = new SimpleButtonView({
    buttonText: 'Hello motto'
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/0z1d9zx5/1/

**Explanation:**

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(this.$template.html());
```

This tells handlebars to compile the html from that template. That means that handlebars internally prepares a javascript FUNCTION with the html. This template variable is re-useable because you can pass different CONTEXTS to it and it will spit out html depending on what context (data) you passed.

This is why I put it in the initialize routine - it only has to happen once - you could subsequently call render 100 times with different `buttonText` and it would be much faster because it has already prepared the template.

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.getContext()));
```

As you can see I have abstracted away the passing of data to the template to a method called  `getContext`. All that getContext does is return an object of key-values which can be used in the template.

Here's the important bit:

I abstracted it away because in an ideal setup you would have your own View extension which would do common useful stuff. In that extension you would do things like handling rendering and you would put the `getContext` function there. All views in your app would extend off of that view instead of straight from the Backbone one, so that for each of your views you would only have to do the bare minimum - i.e supply a `$template` and create a `serialize` method if you wanted to pass any special stuff to the template.

P.S. Note that some html has to go into the template tag - on it's own the template tag is not an element so some html has to be inside it for it to work.